# DirectCollocation not respecting MinimumDistanceConstraint

Tags: drake

I've added a `Box` obstacle to my `MultibodyPlant` using a slight variation of the `AddShape()` function given [here](https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/master/underactuated/scenarios.py#L10). I've welded the obstacle to the plant using [`WeldFrames()`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#a51239c495a32c1f156964cd2c8410c53); the obstacle also shows up in the correct place in the world when I visualize it.

However, `DirectCollocation` doesn't respect the obstacle when I add a `MinimumDistanceConstraint`, and produces a trajectory which collides with the obstacle.

Here's how I create my `plant`, `scene_graph`, and `diagram`.

```py
builder = DiagramBuilder()

plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0.0)
urdf_path = FindResource('models/undamped_cartpole.urdf')
Parser(plant).AddModelFromFile(urdf_path)

# add obstacles
# this function internally calls RegisterCollisionGeometry and 
# RegisterVisualGeometry on the plant
plant = add_obstacles_plant(plant, obstacles)

plant.Finalize()
diagram = builder.Build()
```

Here's the relevant code snippet for DirectCollocation.

```py
input_port_index = builder.ExportInput(plant.get_actuation_input_port(), "input")

dircol = DirectCollocation(
    diagram, diagram.CreateDefaultContext(),
    num_time_samples=num_time_samples,
    minimum_timestep=0.1,
    maximum_timestep=0.4,
    input_port_index=input_port_index
)

# collision avoidance constraints
collision_constraint = MinimumDistanceConstraint(plant, 0.1, 
        diagram.GetMutableSubsystemContext(plant, diagram_context))
dircol.AddConstraintToAllKnotPoints(constraint=collision_constraint, vars=dircol.state()[:2])
```

Am I passing in the wrong context to `MinimumDistanceConstraint` / misunderstood what `MinimumDistanceConstraint` does?

Comment: Could you make sure that both the undamped cartpole and your obstacle have collision geometries? You can check if undampled_cartpole.urdf has defined collision flags for each link.

Comment: A quick way to check for collision geometry, per Hongkai's suggestion, would be to do use [`MeshcatVisualizerCpp.AddToBuilder`](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.geometry.html#pydrake.geometry.MeshcatVisualizerCpp_[float].AddToBuilder), using `role=Role.kProximity`, and then (I believe) something like `diagram_context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext(); diagram.Publish(diagram_context)`

Comment: Just checked the [URDF model](https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/master/underactuated/models/undamped_cartpole.urdf) I was using and @HongkaiDai you're right,  it doesn't have collision flags defined for each link. Let me add those in and see what happens.

Comment: Okay added the collision flags in; on running DirectCollocation, I got the following error: `RuntimeError: Penetration queries between shapes 'Cylinder' and 'Box' are not supported for scalar type drake::AutoDiffXd`

Comment: We currently can't compute the gradient of the distance between cylinder and Box with AutoDiffXd. I would suggest to change the cylinder to a box.

Comment: I changed all the collision shapes to boxes and hit the following error: `RuntimeError: Penetration queries between shapes 'Box' and 'Box' are not supported for scalar type drake::AutoDiffXd`

This is happening presumably because we [can't do symbolic differentiation](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_query_object.html#af3b16adde799eb804619dc86f3703f4f) for collisions. What's the best way to set collision avoidance constraints then?

Comment: It's not doing symbolic differentiation, but automatic differentiation (it computes the exact gradient numerically). Unfortunately we don't support automatic differentiation the signed distance queries between Box and Box either. One solution is to add a lot of collision spheres on your cartpole link. We support automatic differentiation between sphere and box.

Comment: Oops my bad for mixing up symbolic differentiation and AutoDIff. Is there a good way of adding collision spheres to the cartpole link using Drake, after its URDF has been parsed?


I figure I need to `RegisterCollisionGeometry` but I also need a way of filtering out self-collisions between the tiny collision spheres and get them to change their positions with the state of the cartpole, etc.

Is there an easier way of doing this and perhaps directly add them to the cartpole parsed from the URDF?

Comment: Is there some way I can get away with setting simpler constraints for collision avoidance? eg: ask the solver to generate `cartpole_q` for each timestep, such that the bob of the cartpole pendulum (`forward_kinematics(cartpole_q)`) would always lie outside the region of obstacles.

This would certainly be less accurate, but may be sufficient for my purposes.

Comment: I'm considering a simple 2D scenario in case that's helpful.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So turns out the [cartpole URDF model](https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/master/underactuated/models/undamped_cartpole.urdf) I was using didn't have collision geometries defined for its components. It seems AutoDiff works best with Sphere collisions, so I made a rough approximation of my model with Spheres (eg: constructed the `Box` cart as two Spheres placed side by side, the `Cylinder` pole as many tiny Spheres placed in a line), and wrote those collision geometries out to my URDF.

If interested, I generated the line of tiny Spheres using a small string generation script.

```py
sphere_str = '<collision> <origin xyz="0 0 {s_o:.2f}"/> <geometry> <sphere radius="0.01"/> </geometry> </collision>'
for i in range(50):
    print(col_str.format(s_o=-0.01 + i*-0.02))
```

This prints out:

```
<collision> <origin xyz="0 0 -0.01"/> <geometry> <sphere radius="0.01"/> </geometry> </collision>
<collision> <origin xyz="0 0 -0.03"/> <geometry> <sphere radius="0.01"/> </geometry> </collision>
<collision> <origin xyz="0 0 -0.05"/> <geometry> <sphere radius="0.01"/> </geometry> </collision>
...
<collision> <origin xyz="0 0 -0.99"/> <geometry> <sphere radius="0.01"/> </geometry> </collision>
```

Which I then pasted into my URDF.

Adding the Sphere collision geometries into my URDF solved my problem and DirectCollocation started respecting the MinimumDistanceConstraint.